# Нужна ли запятая в подписи?

Tags: пунктуация

Скажем, идет некая статья, а под ней подпись в таком виде:
*Иван Иванов(,)

г. Урюпинск.*
Корректор всегда убирает мне запятую после фамилии. Правильно ли он делает?

Answer (score 2):

Если именно в таком виде-друг под другом- правильно, запятой нет, и точки тоже,потому что это не предложения, не однородные члены, это заголовки, а после заголовков никакие знаки препинания не ставятся. Если бы было написано подряд, то через запятую,но это сейчас не принято,есть правила оформления научных работ, например, вот:

Требования к оформлению статей
 1. http://vestnikvmi.susu.ru/authors/guidelines.html

Сведения об авторах сверху отделяются одной пустой строкой размером 12 пт и оформляются как абзацы основного текста Сведения о каждом соавторе представляются как один отдельный абзац. В сведениях через запятую указываются фамилия, имя, отчество автора, ученая степень, ученое звание, место работы полностью (подразделение и организация) с указанием в скобках города и страны, адрес электронной почты. После сведений о последнем соавторе помещается горизонтальная линия стандартной толщины, отделенная сверху и снизу одной пустой строкой размером 12 пт

Так что корректор прав.